# Java - Ordenar uma List de objetos. É possível usar o List.sort?

Tags: java, lista, classificação

Olá!

Tenho duas classes Turma e Aluno.
Na classe Turma tenho uma list de objetos do tipo Aluno.

A classe Aluno tem vários atributos e métodos, dentre eles o atributo private String nome.

Quero ordenar a list pelo atributo "nome" para que eu possa imprimir em ordem alfabética.

```
Class Turma
...
List<Aluno> listaDaTurma = new ArrayList<>();

//ordenar

//imprimir
...
```

Existe a possibilidade de utilizar o listaDaTurma.Sort() ??

//não sei como

Outra possibilidade bem manual e forçado (que eu sei fazer) é criar um vetor do tipo Aluno e copiar tudo da listaDaTurma, depois ordenar esse array fazendo comparação passo a passo.

//isso é "arcaico", mas funciona.

Alguém me dá uma dica melhor?

O projeto já tá pronto no [Link do meu Git Hub](https://github.com/dgsilveira/TreinoAleatorios/tree/main/RelacionamentoAlunoTurmas/src/entities)
Estou fazendo o método diarioFinal na linha 166 na Classe Turma.
Preciso ordenar essa lista para poder imprimir o diário.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Há duas maneiras de usar esse método de uma List.

Uma é fazendo com que sua classe Aluno implemente a interface Comparable e implementar o método 'public int compareTo(Aluno a)'. Ex https://www.journaldev.com/787/java-sort-list?msclkid=8319900dab1811ec8be249f47c75605c.

```
  class Aluno implements Comparable<Aluno> {

    private String nome;

    public Aluno(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

   \\ ...gets and sets

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Aluno b) {
        return this.getNome().compareTo(b.getNome());
    }
}
```

A outra forma é você criar um classe que implementa a interface Comparator e reescrever o método 'public int compare(Aluno A, Aluno B)'. Ex https://www.javatpoint.com/java-list-sort-method?msclkid=83197a03ab1811ec874365278e3540ad.

```
class OrdenarPorNome implements Comparator<Aluno> {  
  public int compare(Aluno a, Aluno b){  
    return a.getNome().compareTo(b.getNome());  
  }  
}
```

```
Class Turma
...
List<Aluno> listaDaTurma = new ArrayList<>();

//ordenar
listaDaTurma.sort(); //  1th forma
Collections.sort(listaDaTurma, new OrdenarPorNome()); // 2nd forma

//imprimir
...
```

Comment: Deu certo!
Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode ordenar a lista usando a API de stream e lambda do java, dessa forma:

```
public List<Aluno> ordenarLista(List<Aluno> alunos){
    return alunos.stream().sorted((a1,a2) -> 
           a1.getName
           .compareTo(a2.getName()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[Veja esse artigo sobre lambda e stream](https://www.oracle.com/br/technical-resources/articles/java-stream-api.html)